# Is there a way to create/generate PDF forms from XML files using APEX?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

Is there a way to generate PDF files from XFDF with the help of APEX?

Comment: VisualForce. In your `apex:page` tag, set `renderAs="pdf"`. You will also probably need to work with `XmlStreamReader`.  https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_xml_streaming_reading.htm

Comment: Well the problem is with rendering. Whole concept is to avoid re-creating/rendering a page with VF because it might differ than the actual template that needs to be filled. Is there a way to load the existing template and fill in the blanks with data from custom/standard objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that when you mean generate PDF files from XFDF that you are meaning to populate an existing PDF file with data contained within the XFDF.

You should be able to follow the example:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Adobe_XFDF

You will most likely want to tweak the implementation, but should get you pointed in the right direction.