# Convert large XML into PDF format as attachment

Tags: apex, xml, xmlparsing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
<head>
    <link name="NotoSans" type="font" subtype="truetype" src="file:///opt/deploy/netledger-all/netledger/WEB-INF/fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf" src-bold="file:///opt/deploy/netledger-all/netledger/WEB-INF/fonts/NotoSans-Bold.ttf" src-italic="file:///opt/deploy/netledger-all/netledger/WEB-INF/fonts/NotoSans-Italic.ttf" src-bolditalic="file:///opt/deploy/netledger-all/netledger/WEB-INF/fonts/NotoSans-BoldItalic.ttf" bytes="2" />
    <macrolist>
        <macro id="nlheader">
    <table class="header" style="width: 100%;"><tr style="width: 100%;">
    <td colspan="6"><img src="https://456822-sb1.app.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=10144&amp;c=456822_SB1&amp;h=dc145465fb91aeb0ad0b" style="width:100%; display:block" /> <br /><span font-size= "7pt">1804 Embarcadero Road, #200, Palo Alto, CA, US, 94303</span></td>
    <td colspan="4"><span class="title"><b>INVOICE</b></span>
    <table style="padding-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px">
    <tr padding="1px">
    <td align="left" font-size= "9pt"><b>Invoice Date</b></td>
    <td align="right" font-size= "9pt">9/30/2020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr padding="1px">
    <td align="left" font-size= "9pt"><b>Invoice #</b></td>
    <td align="right" font-size= "9pt">20090102</td>
    </tr>
    <tr padding="1px">
    <td align="left" font-size= "9pt"><b>Payment Terms</b></td>
    <td align="right" font-size= "9pt">Net 30</td>
     </tr>
     <tr padding="1px">
    <td align="left" font-size= "9pt"><b>Order Confirmed By</b></td>
    <td align="right" font-size= "9pt"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr padding="1px">
    <td align="left" font-size= "9pt"><b>Account #</b></td>
    <td align="right" font-size= "9pt">105038</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right">Page <pagenumber/> of <totalpages/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </macro>
    <macro id="nlfooter">
    <table class="footer" style="width: 100%;"><tr>
    <td font-size= "9pt"><b>Remittance Information: Payments must be received in the currency of the invoice. Please instruct your bank that wire
payments must be received without conversion or deduction.</b></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
    <td font-size= "8pt">For more information about paying your invoice by credit card, please email finance@accellion.com or call 650.485.4320</td>
 </tr>
</table>
   <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><tr>
    <td class="addressheader" colspan="3"><b>Checks should be mailed to:</b></td>
    <td class="addressheader" colspan="3"><b>Wire funds to:</b></td>
    <td class="addressheader" colspan="3"><b>Accellion USA, LLC Federal ID#:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="address" colspan="3">Accellion USA, LLC<br />PO Box 505281<br />St. Louis, MO 63150-5281</td>
    <td class="address" colspan="3">Silicon Valley Bank<br />ABA/Routing #121140399<br />Swift Code #SVBKUS6S<br />Beneficiary Account #3302984606<br />Beneficiary Name: Accellion USA, LLC</td>
    <td class="address" colspan="3">85-0770328 <br />
     Billing Contact Phone Number: <br />
     650.485.4320 <br />
    Billing and Sales Fax Number: <br />
    650.350.4335
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td align="right" font-size= "7pt" colspan="10">14900</td></tr>
    </table>
        </macro>
    </macrolist>
    <style type="text/css">* {
            font-family: NotoSans, sans-serif;
        }
        table {
            font-size: 9pt;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
        th {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 8pt;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding: 5px 6px 3px;
            background-color: #e3e3e3;
            color: #333333;
        }
        td {
            padding: 4px 6px;
        }
        td p { align:left }
        b {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #333333;
        }
        table.header td {
            padding: 0px;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        table.footer td {
            padding: 0px;
            font-size: 8pt;
        }
        table.itemtable th {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            font-size: 7pt;
            color: white;
            background-color: gray;
        }
       
        table.itemtable td {
            border-left : 1px solid gray;
            border-right : 1px solid gray;
            font-size: 7pt;
        }
        table.body td {
            padding-top: 2px;
        }
        table.total {
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }
        tr.totalrow {
            background-color: #e3e3e3;
            line-height: 200%;
        }
        td.totalboxtop {
            font-size: 12pt;
            background-color: #e3e3e3;
        }
        td.addressheader {
            font-size: 8pt;
            padding-top: 6px;
            padding-bottom: 2px;
        }
        td.address {
            padding-top: 0px;
        }
        td.totalboxmid {
            font-size: 28pt;
            padding-top: 20px;
            background-color: #e3e3e3;
        }
        td.totalboxbot {
            background-color: #e3e3e3;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        span.title {
            font-size: 18pt;
        }
        span.number {
            font-size: 16pt;
        }
        span.itemname {
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 150%;
        }
        hr {
            width: 100%;
            color: #d3d3d3;
            background-color: #d3d3d3;
            height: 1px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body header="nlheader" header-height="12%" footer="nlfooter" footer-height="100pt" padding="0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in" size="Letter">
    <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><tr>
    <td><b>NASA - Jet Propulsion Laboratory</b></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><tr>
    <td class="addressheader" colspan="3"><b>Bill To</b></td>
    <td class="addressheader" colspan="3"><b>Ship To</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="address" colspan="3" rowspan="2">NASA - Jet Propulsion Laboratory<br />Attn: Cortney Wiza<br />39474 Ryan Summit<br />Apt. 606<br />North Albinamouth , CO 34146-5230<br />UNITED STATES<br />thu@kulas.com.3b414.example.com</td>
    <td class="address" colspan="3" rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<table class="body" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><tr>
    <td><b>License Recipient</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Deployment ID# 7583:thu@kulas.com.3b414.example.com<br />Deployment Test Environment  ID# 8946:thu@kulas.com.3b414.example.com</td>
    </tr></table>
<table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px; border-collapse: collapse"><!-- start items -->
<thead >
    <tr color="gray" >
    <th colspan="4">Model</th>
    <th colspan="4">Renewal Type</th>
    <th colspan="5">Description</th>
    <th colspan="4">License Period</th>
    <th colspan="2">Qty</th>
    <th colspan="3">Unit Price</th>
    <th colspan="5">Customer Discount</th>
    <th colspan="3">Total Price</th>
    <th colspan="5">Partner Discount</th>
    <th colspan="3">Total Fees</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">-</td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td colspan="5">Deployment  ID#:7583</td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">KEULPFSAS</td>
    <td colspan="4">Subscription Renewal</td>
    <td colspan="5">kiteworks Enterprise Secure File Sharing  Users with Advanced Governance, FIPS, Automation Suite Support</td>
    <td colspan="4">Jan 1, 2021 to Dec 31, 2021</td>
    <td colspan="2">5,000</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 84.00</td>
    <td colspan="5">96550.72</td>
    <td colspan="3">420,000.00</td>
    <td colspan="5">3.5%</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 312,128.56</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">KEAV</td>
    <td colspan="4">Subscription Renewal</td>
    <td colspan="5">kiteworks Enterprise Anti Virus</td>
    <td colspan="4">Jan 1, 2021 to Dec 31, 2021</td>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 500.00</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">1,500.00</td>
    <td colspan="5">3.5%</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 1,447.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">KEDSAPI</td>
    <td colspan="4">Subscription Renewal</td>
    <td colspan="5">API + Portal</td>
    <td colspan="4">Jan 1, 2021 to Dec 31, 2021</td>
    <td colspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 0.00</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">0</td>
    <td colspan="5">3.5%</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">KEASAA</td>
    <td colspan="4">Subscription Renewal</td>
    <td colspan="5">Automation Suite - Automation Agent and Orchestration Client</td>
    <td colspan="4">Jan 1, 2021 to Dec 31, 2021</td>
    <td colspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 0.00</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">0</td>
    <td colspan="5">3.5%</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">KEVSVR-AV</td>
    <td colspan="4">System Renewal</td>
    <td colspan="5">Existing VMWare Virtual kiteworks Server</td>
    <td colspan="4">Jan 1, 2021 to Dec 31, 2021</td>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 0.00</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">0</td>
    <td colspan="5">3.5%</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">-</td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td colspan="5">Deployment Test Environment  ID#:8946</td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">KEULPFSAS</td>
    <td colspan="4">Subscription Renewal</td>
    <td colspan="5">kiteworks Enterprise Secure File Sharing  Users with Advanced Governance, FIPS, Automation Suite Support</td>
    <td colspan="4">Jan 1, 2021 to Dec 31, 2021</td>
    <td colspan="2">25</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 420.00</td>
    <td colspan="5">112,000.00</td>
    <td colspan="3">10,500.00</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">USD -101,500.00 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">KEDSAPI</td>
    <td colspan="4">Subscription Renewal</td>
    <td colspan="5">API + Portal</td>
    <td colspan="4">Jan 1, 2021 to Dec 31, 2021</td>
    <td colspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 50,000.00</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">50,000.00</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 50,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">KEASAA</td>
    <td colspan="4">Subscription Renewal</td>
    <td colspan="5">Automation Suite - Automation Agent and Orchestration Client</td>
    <td colspan="4">Jan 1, 2021 to Dec 31, 2021</td>
    <td colspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 50,000.00</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">50,000.00</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 50,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">KEAV</td>
    <td colspan="4">Subscription Renewal</td>
    <td colspan="5">kiteworks Enterprise Anti Virus</td>
    <td colspan="4">Jan 1, 2021 to Dec 31, 2021</td>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 500.00</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">1,500.00</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 1,500.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">KEVSVR-AV</td>
    <td colspan="4">System Renewal</td>
    <td colspan="5">Existing VMWare Virtual kiteworks Server</td>
    <td colspan="4">Jan 1, 2021 to Dec 31, 2021</td>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 0.00</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">0</td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="3">USD 0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end items -->
    <tr border-bottom = "1px solid gray;">
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr></table>
<table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><tr>
    <td font-size="8pt">Group Summary by Ship To<br />S1: 39474 Ryan Summit,Apt. 606 North Albinamouth CO 34146-5230, US<br />Subtotal:USD 313,576.06<br />S2: 4266 Latosha Motorway,Apt. 236 Lake Drewfurt GA 71583-7182, US<br />Subtotal:USD 0.00</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><tr>
    <td font-size="8pt">Deployment  ID# 7583: Discount $96550.72 on KEULPFSAS through 12/31/2021 only.<br />Deployment Test Environment  ID# 8946: Discount $112,000.00 on KEULPFSAS through 12/31/2021 only.</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="total" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr class="totalrow">
    <td background-color="#ffffff" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right"><b>Total</b></td>
    <td align="right">USD 313,576.06</td>
    </tr></table>
<table class="total" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr>
    <td font-size="8pt"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td font-size="8pt"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</pdf>
```

So i have this very BIG xml which i need to store it in Order object. I tried below code but its giving me error.

```
Code:-
String xmlString = //above xml in string format..
Order o = [SELECT id from Order where id='8010q000000e8pMAAQ' LIMIT 1];
Attachment attachmentPDF = new Attachment();
attachmentPdf.parentId = o.id;
attachmentPdf.name = o.name + '.pdf';
attachmentPdf.body = blob.toPDF(xmlString);
insert attachmentPDF;
```

[image: Bad Message 414]

How can I parse it and store it as PDF attachment in order object?

Comment: I see you are running it as anonymous Apex. Looks like the block of code is too big due to the xml. Have you tried writing it in a method and running the method?

Comment: 414 error is discussed here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167546/developer-console-execute-anonymous-http-code414#167559

Comment: ok so i have created method and i am calling from that but now i am getting FATAL_ERROR System.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred while parsing the input string. IS it due to SRC attribute in XML? What can be done for that?

Comment: Is this kind of parsing possible in Salesforce?

Comment: It’s not something I’ve done, I’m not sure if it’s possible. Try supplying a small, simple xml file.  If it’s not possible using this approach then you maybe need to look at xmlStreamReader and Visualforce as suggested in Adrian’s comment here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64137/is-there-a-way-to-create-generate-pdf-forms-from-xml-files-using-apex